# How to automatically flag entities once (without PHP error)?

Tags: 8, entities, flags

I created a custom module to automatically flag new entities and update entities. It works :-)

**Here is the problem :**

If I update a neud it is flagged. Perfect that's what I want to do, but if I update the node again, I get a PHP error. This is normal because the custom module tries to flag an already flagged node.

I have the same problem for all entities.

How to fix this ? I am completely stuck with this problem.

Here are the error messages in the logs :

```
Type    php
Date    Dimanche, 20 septembre, 2020 - 17:43
Utilisateur Mathieu
Emplacement https://dev.exemple.com/fr/node/360/edit
Référent    https://dev.exemple.com/
Message Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException : The user has already flagged the entity with the flag. dans Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (ligne 846 de /var/www/www-exemple-com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).
Severity    Erreur
```

and

```
Type    nœud
Date    Dimanche, 20 septembre, 2020 - 17:43
Utilisateur Mathieu
Emplacement https://dev.example.com/fr/node/360/edit
Référent    https://dev.example.com/
Message LogicException : The user has already flagged the entity with the flag. dans Drupal\flag\FlagService->flag() (ligne 253 de /var/www/www-example-com/web/modules/contrib/flag/src/FlagService.php).
Severity    Erreur
```

Here is the code for my custom module :

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Holds hook implementation for the Admin Task Notify module.
 */

use Drupal\flag\FlaggingInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
use Drupal\commerce_store\Entity\Store;
use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\Product;
use Drupal\group\Entity\Group;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\comment\Entity\Comment;

/**
 * Implements hook_user_insert() and hook_user_update().
 */
function admin_task_notify_user_insert(User $account) {
  $flag_id = 'moderate_user';
  $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
  $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
  $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
  $flag_service->flag($flag, $account, $user_admin);
}

function admin_task_notify_user_update(User $account) {
  $flag_id = 'moderate_user';
  $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
  $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
  $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
  $flag_service->flag($flag, $account, $user_admin);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_store_insert() and hook_store_update().
 */
function admin_task_notify_commerce_store_insert(Store $commerce_store) {
  if ($commerce_store->bundle() == 'ephemere' || $commerce_store->bundle() == 'personnel' || $commerce_store->bundle() == 'professionnel') {
    $flag_id = 'moderate_store';
    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
    $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
    $flag_service->flag($flag, $commerce_store, $user_admin);
  }
}

function admin_task_notify_commerce_store_update(Store $commerce_store) {
  if ($commerce_store->bundle() == 'ephemere' || $commerce_store->bundle() == 'personnel' || $commerce_store->bundle() == 'professionnel') {
    $flag_id = 'moderate_store';
    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
    $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
    $flag_service->flag($flag, $commerce_store, $user_admin);
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_product_insert() and hook_product_update().
 */
function admin_task_notify_commerce_product_insert(Product $commerce_product) {
  if ($commerce_product->bundle() == 'produit' || $commerce_product->bundle() == 'service') {
    $flag_id = 'moderate_product';
    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
    $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
    $flag_service->flag($flag, $commerce_product, $user_admin);
  }
}

function admin_task_notify_commerce_product_update(Product $commerce_product) {
  if ($commerce_product->bundle() == 'produit' || $commerce_product->bundle() == 'service') {
    $flag_id = 'moderate_product';
    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
    $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
    $flag_service->flag($flag, $commerce_product, $user_admin);
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_group_insert() and hook_group_update().
 */
function admin_task_notify_group_insert(Group $group) {
  if ($group->bundle() == 'personnel' || $group->bundle() == 'professionnel') {
    $flag_id = 'moderate_group';
    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
    $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
    $flag_service->flag($flag, $group, $user_admin);
  }
}

function admin_task_notify_group_update(Group $group) {
  if ($group->bundle() == 'personnel' || $group->bundle() == 'professionnel') {
    $flag_id = 'moderate_group';
    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
    $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
    $flag_service->flag($flag, $group, $user_admin);
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_insert() and hook_node_update().
 */
function admin_task_notify_node_update(Node $node) {
  if ($node->bundle() == 'annonce' || $node->bundle() == 'article' || $node->bundle() == 'demande' || $node->bundle() == 'discussion' || $node->bundle() == 'evenement' || $node->bundle() == 'itineraire' || $node->bundle() == 'recipe') {
    $flag_id = 'moderate_node';
    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
    $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
    $flag_service->flag($flag, $node, $user_admin);
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_comment_insert() and hook_comment_update().
 */
function admin_task_notify_comment_insert(Comment $comment) {
  if ($comment->bundle() == 'annonce' || $comment->bundle() == 'article' || $comment->bundle() == 'demande' || $comment->bundle() == 'discussion' || $comment->bundle() == 'evenement' || $comment->bundle() == 'itineraire' || $comment->bundle() == 'recipe' || $comment->bundle() == 'produit' || $comment->bundle() == 'service') {
    $flag_id = 'moderate_comment';
    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
    $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
    $flag_service->flag($flag, $comment, $user_admin);
  }
}

function admin_task_notify_comment_update(Comment $comment) {
  if ($comment->bundle() == 'annonce' || $comment->bundle() == 'article' || $comment->bundle() == 'demande' || $comment->bundle() == 'discussion' || $comment->bundle() == 'evenement' || $comment->bundle() == 'itineraire' || $comment->bundle() == 'recipe' || $comment->bundle() == 'produit' || $comment->bundle() == 'service') {
    $flag_id = 'moderate_comment';
    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
    $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
    $flag_service->flag($flag, $comment, $user_admin);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $comment, $user_admin); // get flag status
if (!$flag_status) { // if not TRUE, is FALSE, not flagged
  $flag_service->flag($flag, $comment, $user_admin);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113239/discussion-on-answer-by-no-sssweat-how-to-automatically-flag-entities-once-with).